# Highcharts Boxplots How to get five point summary?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, boxplot

I want to use HighCharts to create boxplots. As I can see in the [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/box-plot) I need to already provide Highcharts with the required five-point-summary, i.e., min, max, q1, q3, median values for creating the boxplot.

Given an arbitrary-length array constisting of numbers, how can I calculate these five numbers efficiently? Is there a quick means in JS to do so?

Comment: You need to calculate the first, second, and third quartiles of your data (Q1, Q2 [median], Q3). There are a number of ways to go about it - I do it server side in PHP for my data, but javascript should be able to handle it just as well.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile | http://thiruvikramangovindarajan.blogspot.com/2014/10/calculate-quartile-q1-q3-and-median-q2.html

Comment: thanks. i preprocess the data in python. there (with numpy) it's even easier to crate the quartiles. so i will do it this way. i am sure, i will have some other questions regarding the boxplots later, but will post them in a separate question of course. thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes, Python is probably the easiest language to do this in. I would guess there's a built in method to return the full boxplot data array in one pass, though I am no python expert by any means

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although you have a solution for doing it server side, I took a few minutes to convert my PHP solution to a Javascript solution, to address the initial question.

step 1) function to calculate percentiles:

```
//get any percentile from an array
function getPercentile(data, percentile) {
    data.sort(numSort);
    var index = (percentile/100) * data.length;
    var result;
    if (Math.floor(index) == index) {
         result = (data[(index-1)] + data[index])/2;
    }
    else {
        result = data[Math.floor(index)];
    }
    return result;
}
//because .sort() doesn't sort numbers correctly
function numSort(a,b) { 
    return a - b; 
}
```

step 2) wrapper to grab min, max, and each of the required percentiles

```
//wrap the percentile calls in one method
function getBoxValues(data) {
    var boxValues = {};
    boxValues.low    = Math.min.apply(Math,data);
    boxValues.q1     = getPercentile(data, 25);
    boxValues.median = getPercentile(data, 50);
    boxValues.q3     = getPercentile(data, 75);
    boxValues.high   = Math.max.apply(Math,data);
    return boxValues;
}
```

step 3) build a chart with it

example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/pvq03hr8/

**[[edit]]**

A quick update that contemplates outliers:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/db11fots/

Comment: According to [this blog post](http://informationandvisualization.de/blog/box-plot), mild and extreme outliers are respectively values  `> q3 + 1.5 * quartile range` & `> q3 + 3 * qr` for large ones and `< q1 - 1.5 * qr` & `<q1 - 3 * qr` for small ones. So you just need the quartiles and a single loop to classify them all. (I'm just starting to get my head into this so I may read it wrongly)

Comment: Correct, it does not, but the original question doesn't ask for it. Outliers can be defined in a number of ways, using the 1st and 3rd quartiles, -/+ 1.5* the IQR being the most common that I have seen.  Here is a quick update that takes outliers into account: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/db11fots/

Comment: I think the "outliers" fiddle is wrong - it has `upperFence = q1 + (iqr * 1.5)` but I believe it should be `upperFence = q3 + (iqr * 1.5)`. It was still helpful to me though, thanks!

Comment: @Carl yes, good catch. Copy+Paste typo. I've updated the fiddle.

Comment: @jlbriggs Regarding the version with possible outliers. If the dataset has no outliers, the calculation of `boxData.values.low` might be wrong. E.g. with the data array `[1,2,3,4,5]`, we would receive `-1`, but actually `1` would be correct. I simply take the min value in these cases using the ternary expression: `boxData.values.low = min < lowerFence ? lowerFence : min;`, respectively `boxData.values.high = max > upperFence ? upperFence : max;` for the `high` value.

Comment: @Uchendu yes, good catch, there should be a check or a parameter for how to handle the lower fence so you can decide whether you want to mark outliers at all, and if so how, etc..